# Postgres How to remove garbage memory capture by data folder

Tags: postgresql

I see in the postgres data folder that 124 GB are being used.

But when I execute the following SQL statement to check the total disk space used by the database, it shows 74 GB.

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(sum(relpages::bigint*8*1024)) AS size
FROM pg_class;
```

I have only database here, so the data folder size must be nearer to 74 GB, but on the file system it is occupying 124 GB.

I could not find out what other disk space is being used. I successfully executed `vacuum full` to clean up disk space.

Can someone tell me what could be residing in the data directory? If it is not required, then I would like to free up this disk space.

Comment: Maybe other databases occupy the storage. What does `select datname, pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(oid)) from pg_database` give you?

Comment: Also: does `select pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_relation_size(oid))) from pg_class;` show you anything different than your own query?

Comment: Thanks, I executed your query, It gives me different result with "pg_toast_16558"=44GB. But I already  executed 'vacuum full'. So it must clear pg_toast memory. Have you any idea about this?

Comment: `vacuum` will not remove toast data - because that's your real actual data. It simply means you are storing a lot of very long strings which are compressed. And apparently your query does not include the toast size of each table. That's why you should e.g. use `pg_total_relation_size()` instead - which includes index and toast sizes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Might post that as an answer

Comment: Thanks a lot @a_horse_with_no_name, I also another database which is postgres 10, I executed select pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_relation_size(oid))) from pg_class;. It gives me 124 GB as result,  and I executed select datname, pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(oid)) from pg_database, this particular database gives me 165GB as a result. then I could not find out where is the other memory used.